# Aerospike - SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Tags: javascript, node.js, aerospike

I am trying to establish a connection to the cluster. Here is the code

```
var client = aerospike.client({
  hosts: [ { addr: 'localhost', port: 3000 } ]
 }).connect(connect_callback(err){
 if (err.code != status.AEROSPIKE_OK) {
    console.log("Aerospike server connection Error: %j", err);
 } 
});
```

Anyone know what's going on?
Thanks

Comment: function connect_callback ?

Comment: `}).connect(connect_callback(err){` is wrong as is syntactically invalid for the same reason `}).connect(1{` would be. It should probably be `}).connect(function connect_callback(err){`. Closing as a typo, there is nothing useful to add.

Comment: I followed the example in the docs.

Comment: And docs never contain typos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be either be

```
var client = aerospike.client({
  hosts: [ { addr: 'localhost', port: 3000 } ]
}).connect(function connect_callback(err){
if (err.code != status.AEROSPIKE_OK) {
  console.log("Aerospike server connection Error: %j", err);
} 
});
```

or

```
function connect_callback(err)
{
  if (err.code != status.AEROSPIKE_OK) 
  {
       console.log("Aerospike server connection Error: %j", err);
  } 
}
```

followed by

```
var client = aerospike.client({
  hosts: [ { addr: 'localhost', port: 3000 } ]
}).connect(connect_callback);
```